# How to verify if another method was called after subscribe using Jest? TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm pretty new at unit test with Jest and I want to test if a method is called after a subscribe.

```
  getRatingId() {
 ...
    this.ratingService.getRating(this.currentRatingId).subscribe(
      rating => this.onHandling(rating) //I need to test this line
    );
  }
```

so I tried:

```
describe('RatingComponent', () => {
  let component: RatingComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RatingComponent>;
  let ratingService: RaitingService;

  const ratingServiceMock ={
    getRating: jest.fn()
  }

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [RatingComponent],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { provide: RaitingService, useValue: ratingServiceMock }
      ],
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RatingComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should verify if the method is called after subscribe', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(component, 'onHandling');
    ratingServiceMock.getRating.mockReturnValue(of(1));
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component.getRatingId();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
   
  });
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')

Answer (score 0):

You should mock return value for service instance that was created in TestBed.
To do so, you should:

1. Get a reference to it the second beforeEach

```
ratingService = TestBed.inject(RaitingService);
```

2. Use it in you test case

```
ratingService.getRating.mockReturnValue(of(1));
```

Comment: I tried but now I have the message:
**Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type '(ratingId: number) => Observable<any>'.**